# SMALLINT to VARCHAR conversion in SELECT / CASE statement in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, varchar

I am working on a code that takes a decimal output and changes it to an abbreviated hex output. However, I get an error message when I attempt to convert the smallint format to varchar. When I run the code below, I get the error message

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'E' to data type smallint

I have tried converting the `SELECT` statement as:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, PCM_ID1)
```

But this returns the same error message. I have also modified the code to

```
...
WHEN PCM_ID1 = '10' THEN CAST('A' AS VARCHAR)
WHEN PCM_ID1 = '11' THEN CAST('B' AS VARCHAR)
WHEN PCM_ID1 = '12' THEN CAST('C' AS VARCHAR)
WHEN PCM_ID1 = '13' THEN CAST('D' AS VARCHAR)
WHEN PCM_ID1 = '14' THEN CAST('E' AS VARCHAR)
WHEN PCM_ID1 = '15' THEN CAST('F' AS VARCHAR)
...
```

and this also returns the same error message. The original code sample is below:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
FROM
    dbo.DMV_All_Tests
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT
         CASE
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '0' THEN '0'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '1' THEN '1'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '2' THEN '2'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '3' THEN '3'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '4' THEN '4'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '5' THEN '5'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '6' THEN '6'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '7' THEN '7'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '8' THEN '8'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '9' THEN '9'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '10' THEN 'A'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '11' THEN 'B' 
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '12' THEN 'C'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '13' THEN 'D'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '14' THEN 'E'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '15' THEN 'F'
            WHEN PCM_ID1 = '16' THEN '10'
            ELSE PCM_ID1
         END AS [PCM ID1 Dec2Hex]) ca
WHERE
    KeyDateTime BETWEEN '2018/11/01' AND '2018/12/01' 
    AND ca.[PCM ID1 Dec2Hex] = '1'
```

My goal is to complete a successful conversion, so that instead of '14' as PCM_ID1 is stored in the database, it would give me the hex equivalent, either as 'F' or '0F'. This would be used to cross-check with our other database, which stores these PCM_ID1 values as hex.

Comment: So is PCM_ID1 a smallint or a varchar?

Comment: PCM_ID1 is originally (smallint, null).

Comment: If you are using at least SQL Server 2012, simply use `format(PCM_ID1, N'X')`.

Comment: This happen because you have an else clause returning the column PCM_ID1 which is smallint. And because smallint has more precedence that varchar, sql server is trying convert the other values in the case clause to smallint.

Comment: why not `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), PCM_ID1)` and then trim it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have recreated your error:

```
DECLARE @X TABLE (PCM_ID1 smallint)

INSERT INTO @X SELECT 14
INSERT INTO @X SELECT 1

    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '0' THEN '0'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '1' THEN '1'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '2' THEN '2'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '3' THEN '3'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '4' THEN '4'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '5' THEN '5'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '6' THEN '6'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '7' THEN '7'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '8' THEN '8'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '9' THEN '9'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '10' THEN 'A'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '11' THEN 'B' 
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '12' THEN 'C'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '13' THEN 'D'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '14' THEN 'E'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '15' THEN 'F'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '16' THEN '10'
        ELSE PCM_ID1
    END AS [PCM ID1 Dec2Hex]
    FROM @X
```

If you that you will get the same error.  The reason is because the `ELSE` in your case statement returns a smallint field which makes the field `[PCM ID1 Dec2Hex]` smallint and you get the error.

If you cast the else as a varchar it will fix this issue.  The problem is that it is trying to convert the E back to smallint.  I hope this makes sense.

```
DECLARE @X TABLE (PCM_ID1 smallint)

INSERT INTO @X SELECT 14
INSERT INTO @X SELECT 1

    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '0' THEN '0'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '1' THEN '1'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '2' THEN '2'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '3' THEN '3'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '4' THEN '4'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '5' THEN '5'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '6' THEN '6'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '7' THEN '7'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '8' THEN '8'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '9' THEN '9'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '10' THEN 'A'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '11' THEN 'B' 
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '12' THEN 'C'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '13' THEN 'D'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '14' THEN 'E'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '15' THEN 'F'
        WHEN PCM_ID1 = '16' THEN '10'
        ELSE CAST(PCM_ID1 AS VARCHAR)
    END AS [PCM ID1 Dec2Hex]
    FROM @X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @input as smallint = 1;
select format(@input, 'X');
```